# Is investing problematic?

Tags: halacha, money, transactions, business, lending-interest-ribbis

Are there any issues involved in investing in stocks or other mediums owned by a Jewish company?

I am referring to ribit (interest).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with interest is that it's risk-free.

The Gemara makes clear that I can own a share in your company; if the company does well, I get more money; if the company goes kaput, I could lose my funds entirely. That's how stocks work -- you can buy $100 in KaputCo stock; that could become worth $200, that could become worth $0.

Comment: Interest isn't totally risk-free. The borrower could default on the loan. That's one of the main reasons for having interest in the first place

Answer (score -1):

An investment implies that one is subject to both a profit and a loss. See Rabbi Reisman's sefer on hilchos ribbis and the inyon of [Heter Iskah](http://matzav.com/business-halacha-the-heter-iska). The discussion would be not about investment in the company, but bonds and other lending instruments in which there is interest. In that case, the question would be "Is there a difference between a company and an individual?". For example there are shiurim by [Rabbi Reisman](http://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Shiurim.aspx?Path=English|EHalach|R7001-1|R7001-1-1&English=True) and [The Laws Of Ribbis](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899061269.html) (as an example).  The Laws of Ribbis, Rabbi Reisman, 22:24-29; 23:1-5.

[Business Halacha: The Heter Iska](http://matzav.com/business-halacha-the-heter-iska) Wednesday March 30, 2011 3:22 AM

> Q: How does a “heter iska” operate?
>
> A: A full explanation of the heter iska is beyond the scope of this
>   column; we will suffice with a brief summary of the four essential
>   parts of any heter iska.
>
> 1. As mentioned last week, only interest on a loan is prohibited, but profits on an investment are permitted. Therefore, the loan is
>      redefined as a “(joint) business investment venture.” The lender
>      becomes the “investor;” the borrower becomes the “active partner” or
>      “manager” of the venture; the principal becomes the “invested
>      capital,” half or all of which remains the financier’s; and the
>      interest becomes the “anticipated profit” of the financier.
> 2. To protect the principal, conditions are stipulated that make it difficult for the “manager” (i.e., borrower) to claim that the
>      capital of the “investor” (i.e., lender) was lost in a failed business
>      venture. This is usually done by requiring full testimony of
>      halachically valid witnesses to claim a loss.
> 3. To facilitate the anticipated return, a stipulation is made that the “manager” (i.e., borrower) will not be believed that the
>      “anticipated profit” of the financier was not realized unless he takes
>      a severe oath. He is given the alternative of paying the amount of
>      “anticipated profit” (i.e., interest) in lieu of his responsibility to
>      take this oath.
> 4. If only half of the capital remains the investor’s and half is a loan, a provision is included to provide a nominal salary, often a
>      dollar, to the “active partner” (i.e., borrower) for his efforts in
>      managing the investment venture. Otherwise, his free service in
>      managing the financier’s half would be a form of interest on the half
>      that is a loan.
>
> Ideally, this agreement should be attached to, or incorporated though
>   reference, in the loan document.
>
> (For further elaboration, see my article, “The Usury Suspects,” and
>   The Laws of Ribbis, Rabbi Reisman, 22:24-29; 23:1-5)
>
> Authored by Rabbi Meir Orlian